# Inline (?) HTML formatting inside a TemplateRenderer

Tags: vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid

I'm just looking for a technique for using basic HTML formatting inside Vaadin 14 Grid TemplateRenderers.

I use many ComponentRenderers that I want to change to TemplateRenderers to improve performance.

My problem is I have a lot of "free form" HTML formatting in the text that is easy to do in ComponentRenderer such as ...

`new Span(new Html("<p>Some <b> formatted </b>text</p>"));`

What is a normal syntax or technique to put that in via TemplateRenderer withProperty(...)?

I *think* just need it to do the same job as `new Html(...)`

Any information much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a dirty trick for making a `TemplateRenderer` use the data it receives as HTML, and that is to assign it as the `innerHTML` property of a wrapper element. This in turn requires another dirty trick with the way Polymer converts between CamelCase and dash-case for converting between case insensitive attribute names and case sensitive property names.

Before showing the example, I also feel bound to warn you against using showing user-provided data as HTML since that's an excellent way of causing **cross-site scripting vulnerabilities** in your application.

With that out of the way, a simple working example goes like this:

```
grid.addColumn(TemplateRenderer.<MyItem> of("<div inner-h-t-m-l='{{item.html}}'><div>")
  .withProperty("html", item -> "<i>Hello</i>"));
```

Comment: Perfect response, and answered more than I was expecting ;-) Hugely appreciated. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

`TemplateRenderer` accepts any HTML, just like `new Html()`. The only difference is that you can bind properties you pass in through `withProperty()`. In your case, you don't seem to need any properties.

To use your example above, you can do:

```java
grid.addColumn(TemplateRenderer.of("<span><p>Some <b> formatted </b>text</p></span>"));
```

Read more about the `TemplateRenderer` on the docs page https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/components/tutorial-flow-grid#using-template-renderers

PS. Placing a `<p>` inside a `<span>` tag goes against the HTML spec (block element inside an inline element).

Comment: Thanks Marcus. My example was just pseudo code and not a good example.
On the screenshot I've put kept the nicely formatted ComponentRenderer column, and the same HTML "content" into a TemplateRenderer, where you can see the content.
I'm just looking to see if there is a way to take that content and get the TemplateRenderer to display it as per the ComponentRenderer.

Comment: I think what OP wanted is to use the whole HTML content as a property value.